# OSX Scrolling Broken In Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Firstly, my environment:

Chrome version: Version 33.0.1750.152

Computer: Macbook Air, Mavericks OSX 10.9.2

Using two finger scrolling, I can scroll up and down a page. However, a couple weeks ago an issue began where I can't side scroll a page anymore, nor do the two finger swipe to trigger the `back` and `forward` function of the browser.

Curiously, this issue goes away in incognito mode.

Does anybody know why this is happening and or how to fix it?

Comment: What extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @Doorknob sorry, how do I check that? I don't dabble with extensions much, if at all.

Comment: Go to `chrome://extensions` (type it in your URL bar)

Comment: I have 3 extensions: avast online security, sight, and smoothscroll. I disabled smoothscroll as an obvious culprit, but no avail.

Comment: Try disabling all extensions, quitting Chrome, and then trying again. If that fixes it, enable extensions one by one until it breaks again, and you'll know that extension was the culprit. If it's still not working, then your computer is haunted and I can't help :-P

Comment: Ah, it was smoothscroll. I didn't quit chrome. thanks @Doorknob

Comment: Oh @RUJordan ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be caused by one of your extensions, since it's fixed in Incognito. Try disabling them one by one (by going to `chrome://extensions` in your address bar) until the problem is gone. Then you will know which extension was causing the problem. (Remember to quit and reopen Chrome after disabling each extension!)

(In this case, the culprit was smoothscroll, as determined in the comments.)